# swift 3 json not working

Tags: php, json, swift

I'm working on a database connection between Swift 3 and a php file.
Sending information to the php will be correctly transfered into the database.

But I'm having an issue when I want to print information from the database into my xcode.

I'm sending this json to my app:

```
[{"latitude":"51.430536341034","longitude":"5.45947450542819"},
{"latitude":"51.4305299243587","longitude":"5.45964865535365"},
{"latitude":"51.4305299243587","longitude":"5.45964865535365"},
{"latitude":"51.4305299243587","longitude":"5.45964865535365"},
{"latitude":"51.4305299243587","longitude":"5.45964865535365"}]
```

I printed this JSON in xcode with:

```
print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
```

I tried 2 options that were described in other topics at this site, which both were about swift 3 and json problems.

Option 1:

```
let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

When I ran the app, there come's an error:

> Signal SGBRT Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x1b2a89cc8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b2a8a128).

Option 2:

```
let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

What happens is the same Signal SGBRT with error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x1b2a89cc8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b2a8a128).

I need to say that I'm not a professional, but I'm a hard learning student with no connections that also program swift. Therefore I hope to get some help here, to finish this function of the app.

If you answer the topic, I would be glad to here some other codes I should try.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, an array is not a dictionary...!! You should cast the result as an array of dictionaries: `[[String:AnyObject]]` instead of just dictionary.

Comment: And you don't need `allowFragments`. Also, `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` is the same as `[String:AnyObject]`.

Comment: @EricAya Well that solves that specific error, but A new one comes up immediately. When I want to get the latitude of it like: parsedData["latitude"] it will say Type '[[String:AnyObject]]?' has no subscript members..

Comment: We've just cast your JSON as an **array**. Of course you can't subscript it like a dictionary. This is an array! Get the items *from the array* (the dictionaries) then use subscript...

Comment: your `json` contaning array  [ ] of dict don't try to get using dict ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSON` clearly says that it is an array of dictionaries, so you should cast it to an array of dictionaries `[[String: AnyObject]]`. Already mentioned in comments. Try below, it might help you:

```
//First you should check for data whether it has value
if let data = data {
    //This gives you an array of dictionaries as per your JSON data. So safer side try to 'guard let' it so that it should not crash if your JSON data is nil
    guard let parsedDataArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return }

    //Here you can enumerate through your array to get each dictionary
    for parsedDict in parsedDataArray {
        //This gives the value of latitude
        if let latitude = parsedDict["latitude"] {
            print(latitude)
        }
        //And this is for "longitude"
        if let longitude = parsedDict["longitude"] {
            print(longitude)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your JSON response that you have added in question, if that was the only response that you need to use `[[String: String]]` instead of `[[String: AnyObject]]` because using `AnyObject` you need to first convert it to `String` then double, so it is batter if you use `[[String: String]]`. Now you have array of dictionary so get all coordinates like this way.

```
let parsedData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [[String:String]]
for dic in parsedData {
    if let lat = Double(dic["latitude"]), let long = Double(dic["longitude"]) {
        print(lat)
        print(long)
    }
}
```

Comment: YESS! Your solution works, I'm so thankfull! Can anybody rate him, I can't do it... But really thanks Nirav D!

Comment: Welcome mate :)